# Is there any long-term upside in having an open-ended vasectomy instead of a closed vasectomy, given that all open vasectomies will eventually close?

Tags: surgery, sex

https://www.theturekclinic.com/blog/choosing-an-open-or-closed-vasectomy-in-beverly-hills/:

> First off, **all open vasectomies will eventually close**. It’s what the body does with leaks. It just takes longer with an open vasectomy. Secondly, sperm are created in the body at puberty, having never been seen before and are “foreign” to the immune system. To me, this means that the potential inflammation, pain and scarring is more likely when sperm spill out of their natural habitat. **It makes more sense to keep them where they normally live within the vas deferens and to not wake up the sleeping giant that is the immune system**. Lastly, my patients just don’t have the same pain rates that are reported in the literature, which gives me pause when I think about changing what I do. And believe me, I am all about change if it’s for the better.

Is there any long-term upside in having an open-ended vasectomy instead of a closed vasectomy, given that all open vasectomies will eventually close?

I found https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/12340687 "Open-ended vasectomy prevents pain, may enhance reversibility" but the study dates back from 1986 and seems to focus on two or three physicians.

Comment: In four days you've asked four questions about vasectomies and they all lean toward "which is better?" questions. Although you provided decent prior research in the first three, the link for this one definitely makes it look like it's a quest for personal medical advice or possibly even spam. Please slow down and let these questions rest for a while and see if they attract answers. If they don't, I don't think additional questions will help.

Comment: @user19840 This is a question about a typical medical procedure, nothing personal here. Asking which procedure yields a better result is very much a valid medical question. I'm limiting myself to one question a day, I think that's reasonable and within the limits established for Stack Exchange. I've added one scientific reference.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you're posting too much.